# Как использовать список из функции в другой функции?

Tags: python, requests, telebot, beautiful-soup

У меня есть функция, которая заполняет список значениями.

```
def converter():
    response = requests.get('https://yandex.ru/')
    page = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    currency = []
    for figures in soup.select('span.inline-stocks__value_inner'):
        currency.append(figures.text)
    return currency[0] and currency[1]
```

Так же есть класс в котором я хочу использовать полученные значения из currency, но не могу понять как это реализовать.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['convert'])
def cmd_convert(message):
    try:
        class Converter:
            def __init__(self):
                self.usd = currency[0] #Список
                self.eur = currency[1] 
                self.rub = sum

            def dollar(self):
                return int(self.rub) / int(float(self.usd.replace(',', '.')))

            def euro(self):
                return int(self.rub) / int(float(self.eur.replace(',', '.')))

        def extract_arg(arg):
            return arg.split()[1:]

        answer = extract_arg(message.text)
        sum = int(answer[0])
        converter = Converter()
        sum1 = round(converter.dollar(), 2)
        sum2 = round(converter.euro(), 2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'USD: {sum1}\nEUR: {sum2}')
    except IndexError:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите сумму после команды')
```

Пробовал вызывать функцию, но это не дало результатов. Буду благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

покажу на примере простого модуля, реализация у тебя будет такая же

напишем первую программу, которая будет выводить на экран через функцию 'Привет! Это говорит мой модуль.'

назовём эту программу mymodule

```
def function():
    print('Привет! Это говорит мой модуль.')

version = '0.1'
# Конец модуля mymodule.py
```

теперь применим эту функцию в другом .py файле

```
import mymodule

mymodule.function()
print('Версия', mymodule.version)
```

Вывод:

> Привет! Это говорит мой модуль. 
> Версия 0.1

теперь благодаря этим знаниям ты можешь применить свою функцию, которая заполняет список значениями в другом файле, но проблема теперь ещё заключается в другом, а что если нужно это сделать в одном .py файле? Тут тоже есть выход.
В функции переменные являются локальными и их не вытащить от туда поэтому можно применить наследования в классе в этом примере

```
class Test_1:
    def __init__(self, arg, arg_2):
            self.arg = arg
        self.arg_2 = arg_2
        print("Первый аргумент: {} \nВторой аргумент: {}". format(self.arg, self.arg_2 ))


class Test_2(Test_1):
    def __init__(self, arg, arg_2, new_argument):
        Test_1.__init__(self, arg, arg_2)
        self.new_argument = new_argument

        print("Первый аргумент: {} \nВторой аргумент: {} \nТрейтий аргумент: {}".format(self.arg, self.arg_2, self.new_argument))
                

Test_2('f1', 'f2', 'f3')
```